# Html.RenderAction in MVC with EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, renderaction

My problem is when I try to render a view with two Html.RenderAction. It says: "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed".

I have Ninject configured in this way:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope;
```

But If I do in the default way...

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>()
```

there's no error.

I have to work with it in RequestScope (so I think), but how can I do it? It seems's that when second Html.RenderAction is called the previous DbContext it's disposed !

UPDATED:

This is the main view (summarized for brevity)

```
@model FoodAway.Model.Product
@Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
<fieldset>
    <legend>Producto</legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
        </p>
    }
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @{Html.RenderAction("IngredientsToRemoveList", "Ingredients");}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        @{Html.RenderAction("IngredientsToAddList", "Ingredients");}
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

and his controller/action:

```
    public ActionResult EditProduct(string name)
    {
        Product product = unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Get(i => i.Name ==name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (product == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return View(product);
    }
```

So, the error in DBContext is when I have this 2 RenderAction methods, the strange thing is if I have only 1 RenderAction there is no problem!!!!!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate the set before passing it to the view. This means that you query the database within the valid scope of the DbContext.

You can do this by using .ToArray() in your controller

Comment: But I get the data after the call to RenderAction, inside the 2 respective action methods. So both calls have their own datas